# How would you write “through our love to the stars”?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Similar to through hardship to the stars or “per aspera ad astra” as many of you already know, how would you write this?
New to this site, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That would be:

> *per amorem nostrum ad astra*

The preposition *per* takes the accusative, so it's just a matter of putting *amor* in the accusative singular and *noster* in the masculine accusative singular (since it has to agree with *amor*, a masculine word.)